# Import python modules from files

Tags: python, file, import

How do I import modules from *py file?
I have file pythonScript.py with lines: import os, sys.
If I import the file pythonScript these lines does not execute. Usung one on these modules I'm getting name error.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code and the full traceback?

Comment: Wait, so you're importing `pythonScript` in your file called `pythonScript.py`?

Comment: Give more details on what you are doing, what you would expect and what actually happens. Currently, this question is *unclear*.

Comment: I have the file pythonScript.py. The script starts with line import os. Then I define a class - someClass() with some functions in it. When I open cmd shell and do import pythonScript and then try to use this module os.path or whatever I'm getting error : name 'os' is not defined.

Comment: Are you trying to call `os.path` from within your cmd shell, or in your python module?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is still unclear. How do you exactly "open cmd shell and do import pythonScript"? How do you "try to use this module os.path or whatever"? What is your environment (OS, Python version etc.)?

Comment: I think I did not understood the way imports work. The unswer below clears everything. I was triyng to import  pythonScript and use modules without namespase

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, might be good to accept it as well.

Comment: Sorry thought I already did it . Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't fully understood the way imports work.

If you run:

```
import my_module
```

then anything contained in the `my_module.py` module is namespaced to `my_module`. So to use this module, you would have to type:

```
result = my_module.some_function(1,2,3,4)
object1 = my_module.SomeClass()
```

Similarly, if you really want to use the `os` import from `my_module`, you have to access it by:

```
my_module.os
```

If you import using:

```
from my_module import *
```

then you can access `os` directly, but it is worth noting that wildcard (*) imports are not recommended.

Just `import os` again in your python terminal.